# ImageId not found in Google Compute Engine using Jclouds

Tags: google-compute-engine, jclouds

I'm creating instance on the Google Compute Engine with jclouds, using the command:

```
Template template = context.getComputeService().templateBuilder().imageId("debian-7-wheezy-v20150710").build();

Set<? extends NodeMetadata> listNode = context.getComputeService().createNodesInGroup("teste", 1, template);
```

But is the error below:

```
2015-08-16 07:27:04 INFO  compute:64 - Image debian-7-wheezy-v20150710 not found in the image cache. Trying to get it from the provider...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: imageId(debian-7-wheezy-v20150710) not found
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.throwNoSuchElementExceptionAfterLoggingImageIds(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:764)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.findImageWithId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:745)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.build(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:688)
    at br.com.clouddeploy.main.TestGoogle.main(TestGoogle.java:47)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `imageId()` you probably need to use the full path to the image. Here's how to find it:

```
% gcloud compute images list --uri | grep debian-7
```

shows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20150710
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20150710
```

So you can use either of these. The one that starts with `backports` has newer versions of packages, but is still based on Debian 7 Wheezy.

Alternatively, it looks like jclouds has the ability to do this URL creation on its own, but instead of using `imageId()`, you should use (see [GitHub code example](https://github.com/pires/jclouds-gce-example/blob/b4cf2c79d810239c01de52c533e616557f5c07ea/src/main/java/com/github/pires/example/App.java#L153)):

```
ComputeService compute = initComputeService(account, credentials);
[...]
TemplateBuilder templateBuilder = compute.templateBuilder();
templateBuilder.fromImage(compute
    .getImage("debian-7-wheezy-v20140408"));
```

Comment: Easier way to get the full path:                                                              gcloud compute images list --uri

Comment: Thanks, @chrispomeroy! Updated the answer. Feel free to edit directly in the future.